# printf() with a function call arg sometimes incorrect

Tags: c, linux, gcc

The C code at bottom usually operates as expected, using gcc on Ubuntu 20.04, but about 15% of the time I get a **huge** result for highest temp:

**Normal**:
Highest temp: 15.30

**15% of the time:**
Highest temp: 970363834813736688025683948382903403895871057............00

If I pull the the function out of the printf() call, things behave as expected 100% of the time:

```
  double max = maxTemp(temperatures,7);
  printf("Highest temp: %.2lf\n", max);
```

I'm assuming the error case is a huge number because there's a double with garbage data somewhere.

Any idea what's going on?

Thank you for your time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double maxTemp(double *temps, int numOfTemps);

int main(void) {
    double temperatures[7] = {6.9, 12.3, 9.0, 15.3, 9.8, 1.8, 0.3};    
    printf("Highest temp: %.2lf\n", maxTemp(temperatures, maxTemp(temperatures,7)));
    return 0;
}

double maxTemp(double *temps, int numOfTemps) {
    double max = temps[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfTemps; i++) {
        if (max < temps[i]) {
            max = temps[i];
        }  
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you add more `printf()` statements to debug your code.

Comment: Why do you call `maxTemp()` twice?

Comment: ^ That is your bug.

Comment: In general, your program is fully deterministic (when the bug is fixed) with no place for race conditions whatsoever.

Comment: Minor: `for (int i = 0; i < numOfTemps; i++)` --> `for (int i = 1; i < numOfTemps; i++)`.  No need to test `temps[0]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
maxTemp(temperatures, maxTemp(temperatures,7)))
```

`maxTemp` expects its second argument to have type `int` and to be the number of elements in the `temperatures` array.  In the outer call, you're passing the *result* of `maxTemp`, which is a `double`, and is a temperature, not a count of array elements.

The compiler should be yelling at you right there - if not, turn on all warnings and treat all warnings as errors (`-Wall -Werror` if you're using `gcc`).

Secondly, the max temperature in your array is `15.3` - assuming that gets converted to an `int` value of `15`, you're iterating past the end of your array into garbage.

Are you *sure* you don't mean to call that as

```
maxTemp( temperatures, 7 );
```

?

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks for pointing this one out.  I blame the keyboard driver.

Comment: Interestingly, -Wall and -Werror did -not- give me any grief.

Comment: @FiveBlue: Hmp.  Well, I could be mistaken in that case (won't be the first time, definitely won't be the last).

Answer (score 0):

as one comment pointed out, you're calling `maxTemp(…)` twice in main.
If you remove the "outer call" you'll be fine, i.e. changing main to:

```
int main(void) {
    double temperatures[7] = {6.9, 12.3, 9.0, 15.3, 9.8, 1.8, 0.3};
    printf("Highest temp: %.2lf\n", maxTemp(temperatures, 7));
    return 0;
}
```

Reason being that `maxTemp(temps, n)` calculates the maximum of `n` temperatures. So it will only work properly (defined behavior) if `n` is the actual number of values. This does usually not apply to the max temp.
This means you were taking values into consideration that are outside of the `temperatures`-array.

## why it worked sometimes (by accident)

Those values outside your array are undefined. Values outside of allocated space are often `0`, but not by definition. This is why it worked most of the time.